# File content mismatch while printing pdf file using pdf995

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

We have a scenario to convert text file to Pdf.so we have used pdf995 to print pdf file. It works pretty well but in few scenarios, it reads the previous file content and printing the PDF file.
We are not sure about the root cause .It’s not happening in all the days. We could see this issue once in a while.

Could you please let me know the possible root cause for this .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8

```
using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
            {
                streamToPrint = new StreamReader(inputFile);
                PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();

                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;                    
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName ="PDF995"
                pd.PrintController = printController;

                // Print the document.
                pd.Print();
                pd.Dispose();                
            }
```

Comment: And `we are not sure` either without seeing your code!

Comment: Please give your inputs